# IF statement to trigger specific conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an IF statement that triggers if assessment results have been placed in columns `B` & `C`.

Some of the info will be filled out, but sometimes there will be some blank cells. I have conditional formatted triggered if there is a name in the header:

```
If Range("C4") <> "" Then
    Call Compliance_Heatmapping
End If
```

and then a formula to trigger cells in column `D` if there is a discrepancy between the two results:

```
With .Range("D5:D27)
         .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B5<>$C5"
etc... etc... to format it
End With
```

but is there a way to avoid any highlighting whenever there is only data in either columns `B` or `C` but not both? Sometimes the assessment results will be inconsistent where a manager will only complete half, but the employee completes it all, and I only want it to apply to when there is data in both columns in that row.

Comment: add something like `not(ISBLANK(B5))+not(ISBLANK(C5))=1` in an `AND` with your current formula

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm confused, what do you mean by `not`? `<>`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav something like: `=$B5<>$C5 & <>(ISBLANK($B5)) & <>(ISBLANK($C5))=1` ?

Comment: Almost `AND($B5<>$C5,(not(ISBLANK(B5))+not(ISBLANK(C5))=1))`

Comment: `NOT` is logical reversal, so `ISBLANK` checks the cell if it's blank, so `NOT(ISBLANK)` checks for population.  TRUE=1 FALSE=0, so TRUE and TRUE=2, TRUE and FALSE=1, FALSE and FALSE=0

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `=$B5<>$C5 AND($B5<>$C5,(not(ISBLANK(B5))+not(ISBLANK(C5))=1))` or `AND($B5<>$C5,(not(ISBLANK(B5))+not(ISBLANK(C5))=1))`?

Comment: The 2nd one should do it

Comment: @Nathan_Sav it says invalid procedure when I have `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($B5<>$C5,(not(ISBLANK(B5))+not(ISBLANK(C5))=1)"`

Comment: 2 closing brackets, you have 1, you are not closing the AND

Comment: Check your formula, by just using the formula in say K5

Comment: @Nathan_Sav works great, thank you so much!!

Comment: No problems.  When you have a moment, look at the fucntions that begin with `IS` and the logical operators like `AND` `OR` `NOT` etc, Excel gives functions, lots of them, so you need to bend a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional formatting function needs to be like so

`AND($B5<>$C5,(not(ISBLANK(B5))+not(ISBLANK(C5))>1))`

`NOT` is logical reversal, so `ISBLANK` checks the cell if it's blank, so `NOT(ISBLANK)` checks for population. TRUE=1 FALSE=0, so TRUE and TRUE=2, TRUE and FALSE=1, FALSE and FALSE=0

Comment: hey, actually ran it, and now it's not triggering anything whatsoever. it runs without error, but doesn't do the `=$B5<>$C5` part of the formula if data is in both columns and differs

Comment: any idea why it would be suppressing the entire conditional formatting, now?

Comment: change =1 to >1 or =2

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
If .Range("C4") <> "" Then
    If .Range("B5").value <> "" And If .Range("C5").value <> "" Then
        Call Compliance_Heatmapping
    End If
End If
```

Comment: this makes sense, but if there is data and both B5 and C5, but data in B10 but not C10, won't this not work? Wouldn't I need it to loop through cell by cell in order for those statements to work?